# How do I work out which of my markers are visible in my Google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Here is what I am trying to do. I have about 160 places of interest. The user enters their address (postcode, full address, whatever) which I use Google to geo-encode. I then create a Google map centred about this point and I add a marker for each of my points of interest to the map (using a MarkerManager). So far so good.

I want to display a list of items beside the map that correspond to the markers being displayed. When the user drags the window, or zooms in or out, or whatever, I want to update this list. If too many items are shown at once, I want to display a message to the user.

What is the best way to do this? I tried adding a listener to the MarkerManager so that when it changed I could work out which markers were still shown. However, the event doesn't seem to fire as I expected, i.e. when the markers being displayed change. Also, I doubt that looping over 160+ markers like this every time is going to be efficient.

```
             GEvent.addListener(mgr, "changed", 
                function(bounds, markerCount) 
                {
                    var visibleBounds = map.getBounds();

                    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) 
                    {
                        //alert(gmarkers[i].getPoint());
                        if (visibleBounds.containsLatLng(gmarkers[i].getLatLng())) {

                            // this will need to be replaced with an ajax call
                            // to get the details from the server
                            strHtml += "<div>Another item</div>";
                            count ++;
                        }
                    }
                    alert(count);
                });
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**: This code works, but the event only seems to fire when the map is moved by a certain minimum distance. So if the user drags the map a short distance, the event doesn't seem to fire.

Answer (score 1):

The 'changed' event only fires if markers have changed, so there would certainly be instances when small movements don't change anything.  MarkerManager expands its working bounds quite a bit, to make things more smooth when moving around (it shows markers that are off the map, within a certain distance).

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to the "idle" event, which is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To Get all the Markers first you have to find the Bounds of the current Viewport then you have to loop all the markers and see if they are contains in the bound. The following is a example.

var bounds =map.getBounds();

```
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){ // looping through my Markers Collection        
if(bounds.contains(markers[i].position))
 console.log("Marker"+ i +" - matched");
}
```